# Drools: How to get all elements not in map

Tags: java, drools

I'm using JBoss Drools 5.5.0 rules.

I have an `ArrayList<ElementDetail>`, and `Map<String, ElementDetail>`, and I need to do print out all the ElementDetail in ArrayList but not in Map.

```
class ElementDetail {
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

ElementDetail class has a name variable which is identified as the Map key.

So far this is what I tried, but it gives no matches:

```
...
when 
    eleList : List()
    $eleDetail : ElementDetail() from eleList
    $map: Map(myMap.keySet contains $eleDetail.getName())
...
```

I was able to find similar posts for matching elements in a collection, but it does not get the unmatched elements for a map:

- [Drools and Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093915/drools-and-maps)
- [drools rule get value from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764465/drools-rule-get-value-from-a-map)
- [to check if an Object is present in List in Drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051361/to-check-if-an-object-is-present-in-list-in-drools)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you'll have to use the negated form of contains, and `myMap` is not bound.

```
$eleList : List()
$eleDetail : ElementDetail( $name: name ) from $eleList
$map: Map( keySet not contains $name )
```